# Setting Character Limit on Pandas DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

**Background:**

Given the following pandas `df` -

| **Holding Account** | **Model Type** | **Entity ID** | **Direct Owner ID** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WF LLC | 100 Jones Street 26th Floor San Francisco Ca Ltd Liability - Income Based Gross USA Only (486941515) | 51364633 | 4564564 | 5646546 |
| RF LLC | Neuberger | LLC | Aukai Services LLC-Neuberger Smid - Income Accuring Net of Fees Worldwide Fund (456456218) | 46256325 | 1645365 | 4926654 |

**The ask:**

What is the most pythonic way to enforce a 80 character limit to the `Holding Account` column (`dtype = object`) values?

Context: I am writing `df` to a `.csv` and then subsequently uploading to a system with an 80-character limit. The values of `Holding Account` column are unique, so I just want to sacrifice those characters that take the string over 80-characters.

**My attempt:**

This is what I attempted - `df['column'] = df['column'].str[:80]`

Comment: That seems like a good idea.  Did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `.str`, like you were doing?

```
df['Holding Account'] = df['Holding Account'].str[:80]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                                    Holding Account  Model Type  Entity ID  Direct Owner ID
0  WF LLC | 100 Jones Street 26th Floor San Francisco Ca Ltd Liability - Income Bas    51364633    4564564          5646546
1  RF LLC | Neuberger | LLC | Aukai Services LLC-Neuberger Smid - Income Accuring N    46256325    1645365          4926654
```

Comment: same as op attempted ~

Comment: I am an idiot sandwich - my code read `df['column'] = f_df['column'].str[:80]` / I referenced two different dataframes. I apologise for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 0):

Using slice will loss some information, I will suggest create a mapping table after get the factorized. This also save the storage space for server or db

```
s = df['Holding Account'].factorize()[0]
df['Holding Account'] = df['Holding Account'].factorize()[0]
d = dict(zip(s, df['Holding Account']))
```

If you would like get the databank just do

```
df['new'] = df['Holding Account'] .map(d)
```